# Tense of the past progressive with always

Tags: verb-forms, progressive-aspect

Hi^^ I'm a student learning English. I learned in a class that either present or past progressive can be used to express a negative reaction to a situation. 
The explanations on the lecture note professor gave are written like

---

The present progressive is often used with always to express a negative reaction to a situation.

> He's always calling me "Sweetie." I hate that name.

The past progressive with always can also be used to criticize actions we feel are annoying, or which we wish to exaggerate.

> At school, he was always getting into trouble.

---

I confused because the explanation about past progressive shows that we use past progressive to criticize actions we *feel*(present) are annoying. 
Does past progressive with always have the same tense with the present progressive with always?

Comment: No, the _getting into trouble_ that he did happened in the past, but we _feel_ that "getting into trouble" is annoying in general (and therefore, still true in the present).

Comment: You mean he used to getting into trouble(although I don't know how he's now) and I still feels him getting into trouble as irritating.Is it right?

Comment: Him getting in trouble, or _anyone_ getting in trouble. It is "getting in trouble" that we feel is annoying, not just the fact that _he_ used to do it.

Comment: So, the past progressive sentences express action that happened in the past and people consider that action annoying generally.

Comment: I only explained why the present tense _feel_ was used. The rest of the rule is interesting, but you should **not** think that is what the past progressive means!!!! It is simply used because something was happening repeatedly or during some period of time _in the past_. Even with _always_, that does not have to be anything annoying, but it _can_ mean that.

Comment: I really appreciate your help! Now I get it^^

Comment: "I remember that girl from fifth grade.. She was always smiling, and everyone liked having her around."

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of misunderstandings here.

The first is that although the *BE always VERBing* construction is often used when you are annoyed at the action, it does not **imply** that you are annoyed. You can also use the construction when your attitude is one of pleasure or admiration:

> Whenever I see her she's always smiling.
>   Even when he's hurt he's always trying harder than any other player on the field.

The second is that even when *BE<sup>past</sup> always VERBing* is used in a context expressing annoyance, it does not ascribe your annoyance to any particular time. It perhaps more likely to express past annoyance than present annoyance:

> He was always getting into trouble, and getting us into trouble with him. I stopped running around with him.

The situation's different, of course, with exaggeration, which is by definition a property of what you are saying now.

The lesson in this is that you have to be careful to distinguish between what a particular form of expression **can** mean and what it **does** mean in any particular context. Much, perhaps even *most* meaning in our use of language derives from the situation rather than the linguistic forms.